# Incorrect output from text-replace loop, unexpected duplicated output

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, function

It's print double, I can't see any error of my code, I use match collection in regular expression, if match collection found 2 (youtube link). the function print 4 images. by the way the function get the youtube thumnails.

Plaintext:

```
string Plainttext = "This selection is automatically generated based on videos that were popular <br/>" +
" in the past few weeks. <br/>" +
" ------------------------------------------------------------------- \n" +
" 'Anniversary Prank Backfires!! \n" +
" http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R7AXBOT8KzU&feature=em-hot \n" +
" by RomanAtwood " +
" 23,268,129 views " +
" ------------------------------------------------------------------- \n" +
" We Are The World for Philippines [TYPHOON HAIYAN] \n" +
" http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1bI8pGLBagY&feature=em-hot \n" +
" by Kevin Ayson " +
" 3,607,584 views <br/>" +
" ------------------------------------------------------------------- <br/>" +
" end of text ";
```

Button:

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Literal1.Text = GetYoutubeThumbnails(Plainttext);  
        }
```

Function:

```
 string geturl;// static string id ;
        protected string GetYoutubeThumbnails(string plaintext)
        {
           var youtuberegex = new Regex("youtu(?:\\.be|be\\.com)/(?:.*v(?:/|=)|(?:.*/)?)([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            MatchCollection matches = youtuberegex.Matches(plaintext);
            ArrayList arrayURL = new ArrayList(matches);  

     //    foreach (Match match in matches)
            for (int i = 0; i <= arrayURL.Count-1 ; i++ )
            {
                geturl = arrayURL[i].ToString();  

                string id = string.Empty;

                Match youtubeMatch = youtuberegex.Match(geturl);
                id = youtubeMatch.Groups[1].Value;
                //  if(match.Success)
                //  {
                sb.Append(string.Format(@"<table  runat ='server'><tr> <td id = 'tduserPicture' 
                    rowspan='1' style='text-align:left'  runat='server'>
                  <img ID='Imagess2' runat='server' src='{0}' Height='80px' Width='100px'  /alt='image'> 
              <br/> {1} </td> </tr></table>", "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + id + "/0.jpg", "www." + geturl));

                //  }
            }

            plaintext = youtuberegex.Replace(plaintext, sb.ToString());
            return plaintext;
        }
```

Output:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: in my original program the palintext is comefrom gmail-inbox-body, I'd already redebug it, and the count is right but I think that the function get all matches and print it, in every count in looping condition.

Comment: forget the 3, the code is the main sample. the 3 is just a sample for clear description of the program process. ok I edit it to avoid confusedness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your modifying the text inside your loop, a separate output should be created rather than an in-place replace.

Don't even bother doing it like that, use a [Regex.Replace callback function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149475%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Knocked this together as a super quick sample

```cs
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        string Plainttext = "This selection is automatically generated based on videos that were popular <br/>" +
" in the past few weeks. <br/>" +
" ------------------------------------------------------------------- \n" +
" 'Anniversary Prank Backfires!! \n" +
" http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R7AXBOT8KzU&feature=em-hot \n" +
" by RomanAtwood " +
" 23,268,129 views " +
" ------------------------------------------------------------------- \n" +
" We Are The World for Philippines [TYPHOON HAIYAN] \n" +
" http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1bI8pGLBagY&feature=em-hot \n" +
" by Kevin Ayson " +
" 3,607,584 views <br/>" +
" ------------------------------------------------------------------- <br/>" +
" end of text ";

        MatchEvaluator evaluator = new MatchEvaluator(MatchFilter);

        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(Plainttext, 
        "youtu(?:\\.be|be\\.com)/(?:.*v(?:/|=)|(?:.*/)?)([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)", evaluator, 
                                      RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace));  
    }

    static string MatchFilter(Match match) {
        var id = match.Groups[1].Value;
        var geturl = match.ToString();
        return  string.Format(@"<table  runat ='server'><tr> <td id = 'tduserPicture' 
                    rowspan='1' style='text-align:left'  runat='server'>
                  <img ID='Imagess2' runat='server' src='{0}' Height='80px' Width='100px'  /alt='image'> 
              <br/> {1} </td> </tr></table>", "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + id + "/0.jpg", "www." + geturl);
    }
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
This selection is automatically generated based on videos that were popular <br/> in the past few weeks. <br/> ------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 'Anniversary Prank Backfires!! 
 http://www.<table  runat ='server'><tr> <td id = 'tduserPicture' 
                    rowspan='1' style='text-align:left'  runat='server'>
                  <img ID='Imagess2' runat='server' src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/R7AXBOT8KzU/0.jpg' Height='80px' Width='100px'  /alt='image'> 
              <br/> www.youtube.com/watch?v=R7AXBOT8KzU </td> </tr></table>&feature=em-hot 
 by RomanAtwood  23,268,129 views  ------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 We Are The World for Philippines [TYPHOON HAIYAN] 
 http://www.<table  runat ='server'><tr> <td id = 'tduserPicture' 
                    rowspan='1' style='text-align:left'  runat='server'>
                  <img ID='Imagess2' runat='server' src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/1bI8pGLBagY/0.jpg' Height='80px' Width='100px'  /alt='image'> 
              <br/> www.youtube.com/watch?v=1bI8pGLBagY </td> </tr></table>&feature=em-hot 
 by Kevin Ayson  3,607,584 views <br/> ------------------------------------------------------------------- <br/> end of text
```